# Linux kernel, const casting function

Tags: c, linux, search, constants

I'm a computer science student and I currently learn C.
A fey weeks ago the l learned about constant variables and constant pointers.The lecturer  mentioned that he found a function in linux's kernel that cast a const variable into a changable variable. The problem is he don't remmeber where he founnd it.

A. Where is this function and what is it does?

B. Why would the programmer do such a thing?

Comment: A. I'm sure there's a mirror of the Linux kernel on GitHub. I'm also sure there's more than one place where that happens. B. Probably because it was necessary.

Comment: The funny thing that if your lecturer found this function in say `3.10` kernel, it may be completely rewritten in `4.1` :) So, please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you are interested in the kernel function or how it 
'de-const'ed (removing the const property) of a variable. In the C-language it's re-casted like this;

```
const int i = 8;

// i=9;        // (compiler error)

*(int*)&i = 9; // (ok)
```

In C, programmers do it either because they couldn't initialise the variable with the wanted value, needed to pass it as an addressed parameter or if they needed to change it anyway.

Comment: I'm intersested to find the kernel function that does that and what it does. This is the Kernel version: "Kernel 2.6.18-404.e15 on an i686" and this is the version my lecturer worked with.